# Doctrine 2 - Zend Framework 2 - Can't create new associations with Form

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm developing my first Zend Framework application with Doctrine2 and I can't make work a simple association. The editing works fine, but I can't get the creation of entities work properly.

My entities are these:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class SpellListDetail{


     /** 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\SpellList", inversedBy="spellDetails") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="SpellList_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) 
     */
    private $sList;
    /** 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Spell") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Spell_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) 
     */
    private $spell;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
    private $level;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="float") */
    private $areaValueOne;
    /** @ORM\Column(type="float") */
    private $areaValueTwo;
    /** @ORM\Column(type="float") */
    private $areaValueThree;
    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\AreaType") */
    private $areaType;
    /** @ORM\Column(type="boolean") */
    private $areaLevel = false;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
    private $durationValue;
    /** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
    private $durationType;
    /** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
    private $durationFail;           

    /** @ORM\Column(type="float") */
    private $rangeValue = 0;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
    private $rangeType;

    /** @ORM\Column(length=2) */
    private $primaryClass;

    /** @ORM\Column(length=1) */
    private $subClass;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="boolean") */
    private $instantaneous = false;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="boolean") */
    private $points = true;

//Setters & getter

<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity (repositoryClass="Application\Repositories\SpellList") 
 */
class SpellList{
    const OPEN_LIST = 1000;
    const CLOSED_LIST = 2000;
    const EVIL_LIST = 3000;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(length=40)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Realm")
     */
    private $realm;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $type;

     /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\SpellListDetail", mappedBy="sList", cascade={"persist", "remove"}) 
      *  @ORM\OrderBy({"level" = "ASC"})*/
    private $spellDetails;
//Setters & getters
```

The third entity, Spell, is a simple entity with id, name and description, with no mapping because I'm trying to avoid unnecesary database calls

And this is the controller

```
public function createAction()
    {
        $form = new \Magic\Form\ListForm($this->model->getEntityManager());
        $form->setAttribute('action', '/magic/list/create');

        $spellList = new \Application\Entity\SpellList();
        $form->bind($spellList);

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $form->setData($this->getRequest()->getPost());         
            if ($form->isValid()){
                foreach($spellList->getSpellDetails() as $detail){
                    $spell = $detail->getSpell();
                    if ($spell->getId() == null){
                        $this->model->getEntityManager()->persist($spell);
                        $this->model->getEntityManager()->flush();
                    }
                }                   
                $this->model->getEntityManager()->persist($spellList);
                //$this->model->getEntityManager()->flush();    
                $this->model->getEntityManager()->flush();
            }           
        }       
        $viewModel = new ViewModel(array('form' => $form));
        $viewModel->setTemplate('magic/list/edit.phtml');   
        return $viewModel;
    }
```

and I get the next error message

```
Entity of type Application\Entity\SpellListDetail has identity through a foreign entity Application\Entity\SpellList, however this entity has no identity itself. You have to call EntityManager#persist() on the related entity and make sure that an identifier was generated before trying to persist 'Application\Entity\SpellListDetail'. In case of Post Insert ID Generation (such as MySQL Auto-Increment or PostgreSQL SERIAL) this means you have to call EntityManager#flush() between both persist operations.
```

So, if I understand the message, doctrine can't persist the whole association because he's trying to persist first the SpellListDetails than the SpellList and throws the Exception because SpellList has no id. I thought that this can be avoided with the mappedBy and persist options in Entity, so what I'm doing wrong?

Is any way to manually call the persist operation on the SpellList Entity before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few mistakes here that i would point out striaght forward

your many side must have some thing like this which i believe is spelldetail

```
  /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

2ndly Remove ID clause from the same Entity which is detail
(your code below)

```
    /** 
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\SpellList", inversedBy="spellDetails") 
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="SpellList_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) 
 */
private $sList;
/** 
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Spell") 
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Spell_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) 
 */
private $spell
```

Change it to

```
     /** 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\SpellList", inversedBy="spellDetails") 
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="SpellList_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) 
 */
private $sList;
/** 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Spell",inversedBy="spellDetails") 
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Spell_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) 
 */
private $spell
```

WHat you need to know is that when there is relation and if relation is correct Doctrine will acutoatically map relation for foregin keys along with constraints.

Also you missed

```
  inversedBy="spellDetails"
```

with your relation with spell entity and i have placed that in the edited code.I am only answering in refrence to actuall question which was associations. I havent seen your controller yet so if you experience a problem persisting/Flush (saving data) comment below

Comment: Thanks!! It worked!!! So, taking this in count, in every "ManyToMany" relationship I have to do this, creating a new Id for the "Relation table"?

Comment: No, for many to many relation there are two approaches that doctrine provide, 1st is using intermediate table with 1 to many join to it using both entities that are taking part in many to many relation, 2nd is using bi-directional relational, in 1st case you have to explicitly declare autogenerate ID as a good coding practice, by 2nd approach you dont need to do ANYTHING doctrine will take care of everything by itself, unless untill relation is Proper and code is Following standards